# Err: item.label.substr is not a function while accessing values from an array using React native dropdown picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react native dropdown picker to show a list of data from an array of objects, which looks as follows

```
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Amit",
         "id":"08941174-9a39-477f-b900-f3affbb43758",
      },
      {    
         "name":"Pranu",
         "id":"c86161ed-690a-4de1-8999-c4a832d786be",
      },
      {
         "name":"Testa",
         "id":"6642bc82-84f9-4298-8000-37a06df298ac", 
      }
   ],
```

I have written the component as follows:

```
 {userObject &&
          userObject != '' &&
          userObject != null &&
          userObject != undefined &&
          userObject.length > 1 && (
            <DropDownPicker
              items={[
                {
                  label: userObject.map((name) => {
                    return name.name;
                  }),
                  value: userObject.map((id) => {
                    return id.id;
                  }),
                },
              ]}

            />
          )}
```

But when I try to execute the above am receiving error as item.label.substr is not afunction. However when I console I get exactly what I want, could anyone please let me know where am going wrong? and what should I do exactly to get the data inside my dropdown picker?

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: is DropDownPicker react-native component?

Comment: it is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker this package

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer

```
var userObject = [....];

const updatedUserObject = userObject.map(({name: label, id: value})=>({value, label}));

<DropDownPicker
   items={updatedUserObject}
   .....
/>
```

Comment: when I return name.name, am already returning string upon mapping, so how do you propose that I do?

Answer (score 0):

items props expects array with label and value property. here is correct mapping.

```
<DropDownPicker
    items={
        userObject.map((item) => {
            return
            {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.id
            })
    }
/>
```

Comment: but the dropdown is now not responding at all, on any click